# Can't delete pods in pending state?

Tags: kubernetes

```
[root@vpct-k8s-1 kubernetes]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   kube-ui-v2-ck0yw   0/1       Pending   0          1h

[root@vpct-k8s-1 kubernetes]# kubectl get rc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     CONTROLLER   CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)                               SELECTOR                REPLICAS      AGE
kube-system   kube-ui-v2   kube-ui        gcr.io/google_containers/kube-ui:v2   k8s-app=kube-ui,version=v2   1          1h
```

Can't delete pods in pending state?

Comment: try `--grace-period=0`, if not help , then  `--grace-period=0 --force` should work

Answer (score 7):

```
kubectl get ns
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
kubectl get deployment -n (namespacename)
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
kubectl delete deployment (podname) -n (namespacename)
```

Comment: Thank you! `kubectl delete deployment (podname) -n (namespacename)` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try the below command

```
kubectl delete pod kube-ui-v2-ck0yw --grace-period=0 --force -n kube-system
```

Answer (score 5):

To delete a pod in the pending state, simply delete the deployment file by using kubectl.
Please check the below command:

```
kubectl delete -f deployment-file-name.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of replicas you specified while creating the cluster, you might be able to delete the pending pod but another pod will be recreated automatically. You can delete the pod by running this command:

```
$ ./cluster/kubectl.sh delete pod kube-ui-v2-ck0yw
```

Comment: Thanks, use kubectl delete pod kube-ui-v2-ck0yw--namespace="kube-system" can slove this problem